# PHP Multi-level JSON response to single-level array (recursion)

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion, categories

I hope someone can help me with my recursion problem. I have the following JSON response and i want it in a single level array with id en id_parent.

**JSON response:**

```
{
    "424":{
        "name":"Category 1",
        "count":4425,
        "childeren":{
            "462":{
                "name":"Category 1.1",
                "count":1231,
                "childeren":{
                    "574":{
                        "name":"Category 1.1.1",
                        "count":527
                    },
                    "581":{
                        "name":"Category 1.1.2",
                        "count":175
                    },
                    "583":{
                        "name":"Category 1.1.3",
                        "count":153
                    }
                }
            },
            "432":{
                "name":"Category 1.2",
                "count":451,
                "childeren":{
                }
            },
            "132":{
                "name":"Category 1.3",
                "count":41,
                "childeren":{
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "125":{
        "name":"Category 2",
        "count":45,
        "childeren":{
        }
    }
}
```

The result i want to get is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 424
            [id_parent] => 
            [name] => Category 1
            [count] => 4425
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 462
            [id_parent] => 424
            [name] => Category 1.1
            [count] => 1231
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 574
            [id_parent] => 462
            [name] => Category 1.1.1
            [count] => 527
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 581
            [id_parent] => 462
            [name] => Category 1.1.2
            [count] => 175
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 583
            [id_parent] => 462
            [name] => Category 1.1.3
            [count] => 153
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 432
            [id_parent] => 424
            [name] => Category 1.2
            [count] => 451
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 132
            [id_parent] => 424
            [name] => Category 1.3
            [count] => 41
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 125
            [id_parent] => 
            [name] => Category 2
            [count] => 45
        )
)
```

This is what i tried, but it gives me a multi-dimensional array.

```
$categoryObj = json_decode( $response, true );
$categories = getCategory( $categoryObj);

function getCategory( $categoryObj, $id_parent='', $result=array() ) {
    foreach( $categoryObj as $id_categorie => $category ) {

        if( isset($category['childeren']) && is_array($category['childeren']) ) {
            $result[] = getCategory( $category['childeren'], $id_categorie, $result );
        } else {
            $result[] = array( 
                'id' => $id_categorie,
                'id_parent' => $id_parent
            );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I hope that someone can help me. I just can't get it right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far. My advice would be to `json_decode` it into a PHP array, then traverse the array bit by bit, checking each element for "children" and then traversing those children too if any. Recursion would indeed be the way to go if you don't know exactly how many levels you need to traverse